# wordpress hero invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Tags: php, wordpress, foreach

I've noticed that the div `image-16-8` from my hero.php file is not being displayed.

When I inspect element I get ***Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in***

Here is the code:

```
<ul data-simple-slider>
            <?php foreach ($images as $image): ?>
                <li>
                    <div class="image-16-8" style="background-image: url(<?= $image->url; ?>); "></div>
                </li>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </ul>
```

I've read a [similiar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40424307/invalid-argument-supplied-for-foreach-wordpress) in which adding an `if` condition before `foreach` seems to fix the problem.

I'm not sure how to do this as I'm a beginner in php.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

**Update** Here is the full hero div -

```
    <?php

function tbhHeroShortcode($atts)
{

    $values = shortcode_atts(array(
        'images' => '',
        'first-line' => '',
        'second-line' => '',
        'video' => '',
        'link' => '',
    ), $atts);
    ob_start();
    ?>
    <div class="hero">
        <?
        $images = decode_shortcode_data($values['images']);
        if ($images): ?>
            <ul data-simple-slider>
                <?php foreach ($images as $image): ?>
                    <li>
                        <div class="image-16-8" style="background-image: url(<?= $image->url; ?>); "></div>
                    </li>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            </ul>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <div class="hero-content">
            <div class="hero-content-first-line">
                <h1 class="header"><?= decode_shortcode_data($values['first-line']) ?></h1>

            </div>
            <h1 class="italic-header"><?= decode_shortcode_data($values['second-line']) ?></h1>

            <div class="hero-content-cta">
                <a class="hollow-button" href="<?= decode_shortcode_data($values['link']) ?>">Learn More</a>

            </div>

        </div>

        <?php if (count($images) > 1): ?>
            <div class="hero-controls">
                <i class="fa fa-chevron-left hero-controls__left" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                <i class="fa fa-chevron-right hero-controls__right" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            </div>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </div>
    <?php
    $component = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();
    return $component;
}

add_shortcode('tbhHero', 'tbhHeroShortcode');
```

Comment: It means your `$images` is not a variable and can't be looped through - check where you're setting this.

Comment: Ok thanks, see the updated question, I've added code to show where `$images` is being set.

Comment: Can you post `decode_shortcode_data()` function

Comment: I've added full code so you can see `decode_shortcode_data()`

Comment: @JordanMiguel you didn't actually post your decode_shortcode_data function - I assume the return type from here is not an array.

Answer (score 0):

check if the `$images` `is_iterable`

```
if(is_iterable($images)) {
    // foreach gets indented here
}
```

Also see the manual page for is_iterable http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-iterable.php

A nice polyfill for PHP5 users (let's hope they are not on <5.4)

```
<?php
if(!function_exists('is_iterable')) {
    function is_iterable($var) {
        return ( is_array( $var ) || ( $var instanceof Traversable ) );
    }
}
```